# Prevent mouse to turn on monitor - Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows

after monitor turns off after predefined amount of time, there is a danger of accidental wakeup by just touching a table. Is there any way not to wake monitor up when it rests and mouse moves just a little?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I know of, as the system is actually on.

The closest setting is to stop the mouse waking the machine out of stand by -

[image]

Sorry I couldn't be more help - the best solution I can think of is to turn the mouse upside down... it will work!

Comment: I don't have this option for my mouse (don't know why). To turn the mouse upside down should work - though I don't know why there isn't a software solution ...

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can come up with is to write a screensaver (.scr, which is basically a win32 application in 32-bit windows, i haven't written this for 64bit system though, last time i wrote one I was doing it for like, what, windows 95?).

A screensaver handle all the key you can handle, but you need to set the `ReallyClose` flag so that when the system sends the `WM_CLOSE` message to your screensaver it does not close immediately. Make it so that when you receive the message `WM_MOUSEMOVE` it does nothing... or maybe display the cursor by `SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW));`