# Listen for screen off event and disable mouse in Windows

Tags: windows-10, display, mouse, batch-file, autohotkey

I want to prevent the mouse from waking my screens (while my PC is on but screens are off or the screensaver is on).

I have read all the resources telling me exactly how "it can't be done", e.g. [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/236708/prevent-mouse-to-turn-on-monitor-windows). Or those saying unplug your mouse, or turn mouse up side down, or prevent the mouse from waking up PC from sleep. - Not interested in those.

I want someone to help me figure out this solution:

- how to intercept the monitor off event, or the screensaver on event.
- if not, then at least intercept an explicit monitor off command that I send by running a monitorsOff.bat file or a nircmd command or AutoHotkey AHK command.
- then run a script that immediately disables my mouse/mice/non-keyboard periherals.
- then, if screens are woken back, or if screensaver is closed, or at least if any keyboard key is presssed, then re-enable the mouse.

Cheers.

### [EDIT]

We have one great solution with AHK by user3419297. Ideally though the functionality should also work if/while windows is Locked (not logged off, but locked).

Maybe somehow using sticky keys like DaaBoss said, or other parts of windows accessibility.

Answer (score 2):

Try this AHK script:

```
$F1 Up::  ; or whatever combination you want
    Keyboard_Blocked := true   ; assign the Boolean value "true" or "1" to this variable
    BlockInput On   ; disable keyboard and mouse
    SendMessage, 0x112, 0xF170, 2,, Program Manager ; turn the monitor off, similar to power saving mode
    ; or:
    ; Run path of your screensaver 
return


; The #If directive creates context-sensitive hotkeys:

#If (Keyboard_Blocked) ; If this variable has the value "true" 

    $F1 Up::  ; press F1 to re-enable keyboard and mouse and turn the monitor on
        BlockInput Off
        Keyboard_Blocked := false
    return

#If ; turn off context sensitivity
```

**EDIT:**

Instead of configuring in the power options the time of inactivity after that the monitor turns off or pressing Win+L to lock the system, you can do it using a permanently running AHK script. In this script you can add more stuff (hotkeys, hotstrings, functions etc.) that facilitate your work.

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
SetTimer, DetectTimeIdle, 50
return

DetectTimeIdle:
; lock the computer automatically after 20 seconds of inactivity.
; Replace 20000 with 60000 for 1 minute etc.
If (A_TimeIdle > 20000) ; as long as there is no input within the last 20 seconds
    GoSub !F1 Up ; jump to this hotkey definition
return


; Press Alt+F1 to manually lock the computer
!F1 Up::
    Keyboard_Blocked := true   ; assign the Boolean value "true" or "1" to this variable
    BlockInput On   ; disable keyboard and mouse
    SendMessage, 0x112, 0xF170, 2,, Program Manager ; turn the monitor off, similar to power saving mode
return


#If (Keyboard_Blocked) 

    ; press F1 or F2 or Space ... to re-enable keyboard and mouse and turn the monitor on
    $F1 Up:: 
    $F2 Up::
    $Space Up::
    ; ...
        BlockInput Off
        Keyboard_Blocked := false
        ; Move the mouse  (speed 10) by 20 pixels to the right and 30 pixels down from its current location to unlock the computer:
        MouseMove, 20, 30, 10, R
        reload
    return

#If
```

Comment: This is pretty good. I changed `BlockInput On` to `BlockInput MouseMove` and `BlockInput Off` to `BlockInput MouseMoveOff`. Couldn't figure out how to unlock it by pressing any key on the keyboard instead of just the one F1 key or whatever.

Comment: I'll wait a bit for alternatives before I accept this answer, because AHK obviously does not work if windows is Locked (which is what my PC eventually does, it locks itself), so if the mouse moves and windows is locked the screens light up.

Comment: See also my edited answer.